# jquery extract value from the next td

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and having a problem getting a value off the page.

This is my HTML:

```
<tr>
 <td>ID:</td>
 <td>4166</td>
```

I want to get the value = 4166

This is my jquery code:

```
$("td").filter(function() {
  var woid;
  return $(this).text() === "ID:";
  woid = $(this).nextALL.text();
  return alert(woid);
});
```

But it's not working.

Thanks for the help.

PS - here is a jsfiddle = [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvnZn/)

Comment: You are returning ``$(this).text() ===  "ID:";`` before the rest of your function is executing.

Comment: Maybe because you return $(this).text() === "ID:"; and it's never executing the other instructions

Comment: Isn't `$('td:nth-child(2)').text()` enough in this case?

Comment: `$('td:last-child').text()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to accomplish everything inside the filter function rather than run code on the element you selected with the filter.

Here is the jsfiddle that outputs all of the text concatenated: http://jsfiddle.net/8gDYz/1/

```
alert($("td").filter(':contains("ID:")').nextAll().text());
```

And here is one that outputs them individually for each matched element: http://jsfiddle.net/8gDYz/2/

```
$("td").filter(':contains("ID:")').each(function(){
    alert($(this).nextAll().text());
});
```